# Multiplication / Division format when using <stdint.h>

Tags: c, fixed-size-types

I would like to understand how work multiplication and division using <stdint.h> (**uint16_t**, **int16_t**, etc).

For example, I guess that the followings produce an **uint16_t**:

```
uint16_t * uint16_t 
uint16_t / uint16_t
```

So there is a risk of overflow.

What happens in the following case ? :

```
uint32_t res = uint16_t a * uint16_t b
```

Does the product give an **uint16_t** result that is then promoted to an **uint32_t** ? In different words, is it mandatory in this case to cast the two **uint16_t** operands to two **uint32_t** before doing the multiplication?

For a division, there is no risk of overflow, hence no need to worry about this case.

Also, what happens when we try to multiply an **uint16_t** by an **int16_t** without explicit casting? Does the compiler performs some implicit casting (for example, casting the **uint16_t** to an **int16_t** and returning a result as an **int16_t**) ?

Let me know if my questions are unclear. Thanks.

Comment: "For a division, there is no risk of overflow" --> Yet division by 0 is a risk.

Comment: `uint32_t res = uint16_t a * uint16_t b` better as `uint32_t res = (uint32_t) a * b`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're right, I forgot this special case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.5.5 specifies how the multiplication and divisor operators behave. Paragraph 3 says:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

6.3.1.8 1 specifies the usual arithmetic conversions:

> … First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain [complex or real], to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `double`.
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `float.`
>
> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
> - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Rank has a technical definition that largely corresponds to width (number of bits in an integer type).

> What happens in the following case ? :
>
> `uint32_t res = uint16_t a * uint16_t b`

In typical modern C implementations, `int` is 32 bits, so it can represent all the values of `uint16_t`. So `a` and `b` are promoted to `int`. Then no further conversion is needed. The multiplication is performed in the `int` type. This can overflow. For example, if `a` and `b` are both 50,000, then the product would be 2,500,000,000, but the largest value a 32-bit `int` can represent is 2,147,483,647. The C standard does not define the behavior when overflow occurs. To avoid this, you should convert one or both operands to a sufficiently wide type, as with `uint32_t res = (uint32_t) a * b;`.

Supposing that `uint32_t` is `unsigned int`, the integer promotions will leave `(uint32_t) a` as `unsigned int`. `b` will be promoted to `int` as before, but then the usual arithmetic conversions will convert it to `unsigned int`, per the third bullet item, and the arithmetic will be performed with `unsigned int`, and there will be no overflow.

The above assumed `int` can represent all the values of a `uint16_t`. If it cannot, then the operands will not be promoted by the integer promotions; they will be left as the `uint16_t` type. The multiplication will be performed in the `uint16_t` type. If the result cannot be represented, information will be lost. This is not overflow, because the C standard defines arithmetic in unsigned integer types to wrap modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>, where *N* is the number of bits in the type. So the behavior is defined, but it will not give the normal mathematical result.

To get the desired result, convert one or both operands to a sufficiently wide type, as with the previous case: `uint32_t res = (uint32_t) a * b;`.

> … is it mandatory in this case to cast the two `uint16_t` operands to two `uint32_t` before doing the multiplication?

The C standard does not require this.

Some coding standards require this.

Some compilers may warn you in some circumstances where they can detect an issue.

Getting correct answers requires you to cast where the desired mathematical answer is not representable in the type that results from the usual arithmetic conversions. In any code where you cannot prove that the usual arithmetic conversions produce a type that can represent all desired answers, you should include a cast to a type that can.

> Also, what happens when we try to multiply an `uint16_t` by an `int16_t` without explicit casting?

In the typical case today, with 32-bit `int`, both operands are promoted to `int`, and the arithmetic is performed with `int`. Once again, you should cast one or both operands to a type sufficiently wide for the desired result.

With a 16-bit `int`, neither operand is promoted. Then the usual arithmetic conversions convert them both to `uint16_t`, per the third bullet item, and the multiplication is performed using `uint16_t`.

> Does the compiler performs some implicit casting (for example, casting the `uint16_t` to an `int16_t` and returning a result as an `int16_t`) ?

There is an implicit conversion to `uint16_t`, as described above. (This is not a cast. The word “cast” is used for an explicit operator in source code, of the form, `(type)`. Because it is an explicit operator, a cast is never implicit. Casts perform conversions. Other conversions can be implicit.)

In `a * b`, where `a` is `uint16_t` and `b` is `int16_t`, there is no implicit conversion to `int16_t`. There will be a conversion or conversions to `uint16_t` or `int`, depending on the width of `int`. If you assign the result to an `int16_t` object, the assignment will induce a conversion to `int16_t`. If the value to be assigned cannot be represented in `int16_t`, the result (which may be a signal) is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

There are... cases. Operands of `*` undergo *integer promotions*, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion .

> Does the product give an uint16_t result

Let's assume a sane, common system - `int` has 32-bit. *On such system* `int` can hold any value of `uint16_t`. Both operands are promoted to `int` before doing anything.

On a system with 32-bit `int`: no, they give an `int` result.

> that is then promoted to an uint32_t ?

Yes. The result is *converted* to an `uint32_t`.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment :

> Assignment performs implicit conversion from the value of rhs to the type of lhs and then replaces the value in the object designated by lhs with the converted value of rhs.

How is it converted? From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion :

> if the target type is unsigned, the value 2^b
> , where b is the number of bits in the target type, is repeatedly subtracted or added to the source value until the result fits in the target type. In other words, unsigned integers implement modulo arithmetic.

The result of `uint16_t * uint16_t` has to be in range of `uint32_t` - so there is nothing will happen.

> is it mandatory in this case to cast the two uint16_t operands to two uint32_t before doing the multiplication?

No, it's not mandatory. C is a programming language with *implicit* conversions and promotions, they are done implicitly.

There are "software development guidelines" that "enhance" C for security reasons and require explicitly casting, most notably [MISRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C).

> what happens when we try to multiply an uint16_t by an int16_t without explicit casting?

They both get promoted to an `int`.

But let's consider something interesting - `int` can have 16-bits, like on xc8 compiler. On such systems, the types do not get promoted and stay - `int16_t` and `uint16_t`. Then, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion :

> If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type.

`int16_t` and `uint16_t` have the same conversion rank - unsinged and signed same types have equal ranks. So, the `int16_t` will be *converted* to `uint16_t` and then it becomes `uint16_t * uint16_t`.

`int16_t` will be converted by "repeatedly subtracting or adding" the value of `2^16 = 65536` until it in the range of `uint16_t`. So, for example, `(uint16_t)-5` is equal to `65531`, because `-5 + 65536 = 65531`.

> Does the compiler performs some implicit casting

Yes!

Comment: Re “Yes!”: For that question, OP does not give any context that would indicate the result is converted to an `int16_t`.

Comment: "uint16_t * uint16_t has to be in range of uint32_t" is amiss.  `uint16_t * uint16_t` risks `int` overflow, UB.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this was a general question, but as I read your explanations I realize that yes it depends on the architecture used. I use riscv-32 bits.